# How to add additional data to a series?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: example]

I'm pretty new in this, so i'm sorry if I'm not asking the question with the correct terms.

In the photo there is a simple example to a follow up we do for our customer support team.

The yellow series represent the number of answered inbound calls. I want to add on top of that column also the percentage of calls not answered.In the most right group of columns, the inbound calls are 20, and the answered calls are 10. I want to see on top of that 10 - 50% abandon rate - so only 10 out of the 20 calls were answered. I have a function to auto calculate it in the table I made, but I can't add it to this Graph as a column, because I can't compare in the same graph numbers and percentages.

Comment: Welcome. It's not really another value in the same series; it's a different value altogether. I'd use a combo chart. Let the values in the existing series be `columns` on the `Left axis`. Then add a second Y axis [doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9085334?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and made the "abandonment rate" be a `line` on the `Right axis`. Enable `data labels`. You could even add a `Trendline` if it is significant.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the abandonment rate is not another value in the existing series - it is a different value altogether and needs to be identified differently.

In this answer, I have used a combo chart with the existing series assigned to the "Left axis" as columns, and the abandonment rate assigned to the "Right axis" as a line.

---

**The completed chart**

[image: Graph Screen shot]

---

**Chart Setup and customisation**

[image: Chart setup]   [image: Chart customisation]

---